# Can I use robots.txt to block any directory tree that starts with numbers?

Tags: robots.txt

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to handle this, but I had made a temporary mistake with my rewrites and Google (possibly others) picked up on it, now it has them indexed and keeps coming up with errors.

Basically, I'm generating URLs based on a variety of factors, one being the id of an article, which is automatically generated.  These then redirect to the correct spot.

I had first accidentally set up stuff like this:

/2343/news/blahblahblah

/7645/reviews/blahblahblah

Etc.

This was a problem for a lot of reasons, the main one being that there would be duplicates and stuff wasn't pointing to the right places and yada yada. And I fixed them to this now:

/news/2343/blahblahblah

/reviews/7645/blahblahblah

Etc.

And that's all good.  But I want to block anything that falls into the pattern of the first.  In other words, anything that looks like this:

**** = any numerical pattern

/****/anythingelsehere

So that Google (and any others who have maybe indexed the wrong stuff) stops trying to look for these URLs that were all messed up and that don't even exist anymore.  Is this possible?  Should I even be doing this through robots.txt?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13863586/1591669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to setup a robots.txt for that, just return 404 errors for those urls and Google and other search engines will eventually drop them.

Google also has Webmaster tools which you can use to deindex urls. I'm pretty sure other hosts have similar things.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to wrap my head around this.  Where would I return a 404 error?  I am doing the rewrites in my .htaccess file, so I somehow return a 404 from there, or do I have to rewrite them to a php page and do a 404 there?  I'm sorry, I've never actually set up any 404 stuff.

Comment: 404 is page not found. If no page exists, it will automatically return a 404, and google will recognize this as a broken URL and remove it from its index automatically.

Comment: You can also return a 404 from PHP by setting the header -- header("Status: 404 Not Found");

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: Yes, you can block any URLs that start with a number.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /0
Disallow: /1
Disallow: /2
Disallow: /3
Disallow: /4
Disallow: /5
Disallow: /6
Disallow: /7
Disallow: /8
Disallow: /9
```

It would block URLs like:

- `example.com/1`
- `example.com/2.html`
- `example.com/3/foo`
- `example.com/4you`
- `example.com/52347612`

These URLs would still be allowed:

- `example.com/foo/1`
- `example.com/foo2.html`
- `example.com/bar/3/foo`
- `example.com/only4you`