# Common rule in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

How can I disallow URLs like `1.html, 2.html, ..., [0-9]+.html` (in terms of regexp) with `robots.txt`?

Comment: Generally not allowed but Google will recognize very basic pattern. Please specify your exact case to see if it could be done. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=40360&rd=1

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13355409/1591669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original robots.txt specification doesn't support regex/wildcards. However, you could block URLs like these:

- example.com/1.html
- example.com/2367123.html
- example.com/3
- example.com/4/foo
- example.com/5/1
- example.com/6/
- example.com/7.txt
- example.com/883
- example.com/9to5
- …

with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /0
Disallow: /1
Disallow: /2
Disallow: /3
Disallow: /4
Disallow: /5
Disallow: /6
Disallow: /7
Disallow: /8
Disallow: /9
```

If you want to block only URLs starting with a single numeral followed by `.html`, just append `.html`, like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /0.html
Disallow: /1.html
…
```

However, this *wouldn't* block, for example, `example.com/12.html`

Comment: But I have unlimited number of such pages :)

Comment: @Dmytro: Well, this is no problem if **a)** they *all* start with `0`…`9`, AND **b)** you *don't* want to allow any URLs that start with `0`…`9`.

Comment: I added another variant if all your URLs end with a numeral followed by `.html`. You should describe exactly what your URLs look like that you want to block and what your URLs look like that you want to allow, if my example don't work for you.